# Does WSO2 Identity Server 4.6 support obligations?

Tags: wso2, xacml3, wso2-identity-server

I believe that support for obligations are included in XACML 3.0, e.g.:

https://docs.wso2.org/display/IS450/Managing+Entitlement#ManagingEntitlement-ImprovementsinObligation

and that WSO2 (4.6) is supposed to support XACML 3.0.  However, I haven't been able to find any information on enabling this support in WSO2.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Obligations are supported by WSO2IS. It is basically about the underline XACML engine..  WSO2IS uses Balana XACML engine that supports obligations and advices. You can write a policy with obligations and try out with WSO2 Identity Server.

Comment: Hi @Asela is there any new updates for Delegation profile in Balana?